# Does Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) decrements the number of instances in an AutoScaling group when using CloudWatch policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

Let's say that I have an AutoScaling group with `min=1`, `max=10` and currently 10 instances deployed.

I am using CloudWatch metrics for the scaling policies (e.g., CPU load).

At some point, one of the instances starts failing the health checks of the ELB (a process dies), but CPU load for this instance is low.

The ELB stops sending requests to that instance.

My questions are:

- Is this instance removed from the autoscaling group?
- If not, don't I end-up with 9 working instances instead of 10 (one is still there but not doing anything)?

The behavior that I would expect is that when an instance becomes out of service, it disappears from the autoscaling group, so the group can keep scaling to one more instance (to replace the faulty one) if needed.

Comment: You want to stop or terminate the instance that a specific process on it fails, right?

Answer (score 1):

> If you have associated your Auto Scaling group with a load balancer
>   and have chosen to use the Elastic Load Balancing health checks, Auto
>   Scaling determines the health status of the instances by checking both
>   the instance status and health checks. Auto Scaling marks an instance
>   unhealthy if the instance is in a state other than running, the system
>   status is impaired, or Elastic Load Balancing reports that the
>   instance failed the health checks.

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-maintain-instance-levels.html

To summarize, the autoscaling group will replace the instance that was marked as unhealthy by the ELB.

Comment: But this is true if you set the "Health Check Type" of the AutoscalingGroup to `ELB`, but I need to have `EC2` there.

Comment: If you select `EC2` then autoscaling looks at *both* the ELB health checks and the instance status checks. (From the excerpt in my answer from the AWS documentation page.)

Comment: @jbird: Its the other way around. If you set ELB the ASG will use both ELB health checks and EC2 health checks. Read what you quoted again :)